# Linux Application switcher by searching open windows

Tags: linux, desktop-client, task-management

I am looking for something similar to [Switcheroo](https://github.com/kvakulo/Switcheroo),
but for latest Ubuntu (with Gnome) or Linux Mint Cinnamon.

[Switcheroo](https://github.com/kvakulo/Switcheroo) provides the ability to search for the open window by typing the name of the window. E.g., Right now I have the following windows open

- Firefox - Stack Overflow
- Terminal - /dusr/bin/
- Settings
- Chrome - Gmail

I can hit the [Switcheroo](https://github.com/kvakulo/Switcheroo) shortcut – currently configured to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> – and start typing the name of the window, e.g., Chrome. 
As I type, the list of windows narrows and I can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate to the selected window.

I genreallly have over 20 different application open at any time, and using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to find the window to navigate to is really painful. I would like to type-search-enter to navigate.

I am quite certain I have seen something similar for Ubuntu, but I can’t recollect how I enabled it or if it only worked in Unity.

I am currently using Linux Mint, so ideally it would be nice to have something that would work in Linux Mint.